# В методе Get работает, в POST нет

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

есть метод:
в этом исполнении currentUser  равен нулл

```
        [HttpPost("[action]/{post}")]
        public async Task SaveUserPost(string post)
        {
            var currentUser = await db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
            if (currentUser != null)
            {               
                currentUser.UserPosts
                    .Add(new UserPost { AuthorPost=currentUser.UserName, Post = post, TimeOfPublication = DateTime.Now, User=currentUser });
                db.Update(currentUser);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
```

если переделываю на гет, то все работает идеально

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{post}")]
        public async Task SaveUserPost(string post)
        {
            var currentUser = await db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
            if (currentUser != null)
            {               
                currentUser.UserPosts
                    .Add(new UserPost { AuthorPost=currentUser.UserName, Post = post, TimeOfPublication = DateTime.Now, User=currentUser });
                db.Update(currentUser);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
```

С клиента в обоих случаях уходит токен с данными и все что необходимо, почему в пост методе я не могу получить идентифицированного юзера, а в гет все без проблем? Это ошибка в моем проекте? или есть законные основания?:)

Answer (score 0):

Решил, на клиенте шлю запрос

```
saveUserPost(post) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    return this.http.post(this.urlUser + "/" + "SaveUserPost", { text: post }, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      })
    });
  }
```

на сервере создал модель с текстовым полем, и принимаю эту модель

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
        public async Task SaveUserPost([FromBody] PostModel post)
        {
            var currentUser = await db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            if (currentUser != null)
            {               
                currentUser.UserPosts
                    .Add(new UserPost { AuthorPost=currentUser.UserName, Post = post.Text, TimeOfPublication = DateTime.Now, User=currentUser });
                db.Update(currentUser);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
```